# Dataweave - Transform CSV structure

Tags: csv, dataweave, mulesoft

I'm trying to transform the structure of a .CSV using Dataweave 2.0

Here is my input csv example:

```
gaID,gender,age,city,state
GA1.3.332,male,20-30,,
GA1.3.1041d,female,30-40,Sao Paulo,Sao Paulo
GA1.3.1041d,,,Sao Paulo
```

and I need to create this output:

```
GA1.3.332^gender:male;age:20-30
GA1.3.1041d^gender:female;age:30-40;city:Sao Paulo;state:Sao Paulo
GA1.3.1041d^state:Sao Paulo
```

Notice that when the input attributes are null they should not be present in the output and that's the problem I have.

So far I have this code but does not fully comply with my need because its writing all the attributes even if are null or not.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv header=false, separator=';'
---
payload map {
 c1: $.gaID ++ "^" ++ "gender:" ++ $.gender,
 c2: "age:" ++ $.age,
 c3: "city:" ++ $.city,
 c4: "state:" ++ $.state,
 c5: "maritalStatus:" ++ $.martitalStatus,
 c6: "householdIncome:" ++ $.householdIncome,
 c7: "bradSegCustomer:" ++ $.bradSegCustomer,
 c8: "bradCustomer:" ++ $.bradCustomer,
 c9: "BankClientSegment:" ++ $.BankClientSegment,
 c10: "main_account:" ++ $.main_account,
 c11: "occupation:" ++ $.occupation,
 c12: "presenceofChildren:" ++ $.presenceofChildren,
}
```

output from my code:

```
GA1.3.332^gender:male;age:20-30;city:;state:
GA1.3.1041d^gender:female;age:30-40;city:Sao Paulo;state:Sao Paulo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted it to be dynamic, except the special transformation for the gaID field, then added the condition to filter the elements that have an empty value using filterObject().

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/csv header=false, separator=';'
---
payload map 
    ($ 
      filterObject ((value, key, index) -> !isEmpty(value))
      mapObject((value, key, index) -> 
        (key): if (key as String != "gaID") 
                    (key as String ++ ":" ++ value) 
               else (value ++ "^") 
    )
)
```

Input:

```
gaID,gender,age,city,state
GA1.3.332,male,20-30,,
GA1.3.1041d,female,30-40,Sao Paulo,Sao Paulo
GA1.3.1041d,,,Sao Paulo
```

Output:

```
GA1.3.332^;gender:male;age:20-30
GA1.3.1041d^;gender:female;age:30-40;city:Sao Paulo;state:Sao Paulo
GA1.3.1041d^;city:Sao Paulo
```

With a CSV format you can't remove the separator between fields. If the first ';' is a problem then we need to use a String output and concatenate the fields as needed though we lose some of the simplicity of the CSV solution:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload map 
    ($ 
        filterObject ((value, key, index) -> !isEmpty(value))
        mapObject((value, key, index) -> 
            (key): if (key as String != "gaID") 
                        (key as String ++ ":" ++ value) 
                else (value ++ "^") 
        )
        pluck ($)
        reduce  ((item, acc="") -> acc ++ item ++";")
    ) reduce ($$ ++ "\n" ++ $)
```

This scripts gives an extra `;` at the end of each line. If that is a problem it should not be difficult to add a function to remove it.

Comment: thanks for your reply Alec. I'm trying to understand how to change your code in order to avoid having      gaID^;    in all the records

Comment: I'm not seeing that in my test. Are you using the same input from your description?

Comment: I added input and output to my test and simplified the script a bit.

Comment: from your output, how could I remove the ; after the ^

Comment: I have updated my answer with a new script for the later case. Because the output is not really compliant with the CSV format I developed an alternative.

Comment: thanks for your explanation and patience Aled